# 0 + integer is weird in JS

Tags: javascript, types, numbers

Go to your browser's JS console and try these:

```
-14
// -14

-014
// -12

-24
// -24

-024
// -20

-0024
// -20

012
// 10
```

Why is this 0-integer construct giving me results that are 2 smaller in absolute value?

Comment: have you heard of octal numbers. 014 is nothing but octal representation of 12. same goes with 024.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Never write a number with a leading zero (like 07).
Some JavaScript versions interpret numbers as octal if they are written with a leading zero."
(see: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: Usual W3Schools... They could have choosen a different number for their example. 07 === 7.